# How to order TestClasses in MSTest

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium, mstest

I am writing selenium test cases of workflow application.
I am having two diffrent TestClasses in Mstest Project, Let say ClassA,ClassB,ClassC and so on.

How to order Execution of TestClasses in Mstest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the execution order - the test should be able to run in any order. They should not depend on any global state - that will only lead to pain in the end. Try to remove all dependencies between tests and test classes.